# execute trigger when data is export from csv

Tags: sql, postgresql, ubuntu, bigdata

We have seven tables in postgres database.t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t,t7 Each table contains various columns with duplicate product_id number

The product_id number is exists is each table.That means

```
 t1 --> 123(product_id)
 t1 --> 123(with various other column data)
 t2 --> 123 upto  t7
```

this "123" product id will be existing in each table upto t7.And also,the table will have more than one same product_ids.

Current requirement is to process all product_id's in my server, I need to create intermediate table with unique product ids.

whenever i am updating the tables(t1..t7) the intermediate table has to be triggered to update.

**Edit1**:
   The Intermediate view has to be generated by making all seven tables together.

When I am again importing few more rows from csv/**(copy tablename from csvpath...)** to these seven tables.The intermediate view also need to be computed and updated by the trigger method

Because this is the frequent operation.Updating the tables from csv and again computing and updating the intermediate view.

So ,How it supposed to write the trigger when updating the seven tables by importing from csv?

Comment: Please, precise, what is “export from”? Do you mean data import here?

Comment: @vyegorov yes importing from csv only.

Answer (score 1):

Don't create a table, create a view that selects from those tables.

```
create or replace view all_product_ids
as
 select product_id
 from t1
 union 
 select product_id
 from t2
 union 
 ... you get the picture ...
```

Once you have done that, re-think your database model. By the little information you have provided it sure sounds like your model is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the PostgreSQL documentation on [PL/pgSQL triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-trigger.html), and especially on [this example](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-AUDIT-EXAMPLE), your activities looks similar.

Comment: yeah ..In this example The have given the trigger method for INSERT ON,UPDATE ON,DELETE ON queries..I will use "copy table name from csvpath" command to update the tables.So,How we have to apply the trigger logic for this kind of insertion?

Comment: @saravana, `COPY` is actually inserting data in a bulk way.